# Assign problems to students

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a pool of problems $P$ and class of students $C$. I want to assign each student $m$ problems, such that each pair of assignments have an intersection not bigger than $k$. That is form a pool of *lists of problems* $F$ such that
$$
C \hookrightarrow F \subseteq 2^P, \quad
|s| = m, \quad |s_1 \cap s_2| \le k, \quad
\forall s, s_1, s_2 \in F.
$$
How can I minimize my pool $P$? What I need is some algorithm to find such set $F$ and estimate $|P| \ge n$, so that algorithm works (not the minimal P, I guess it's harder).

For a more concrete problem, say $|C| = 30, m = 10, k = 2$.

P.S. it's getting harder to avoid cheaters in my class. Math is my approach :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help in terms of the question. However, I can help with the P.S. - try finding UKMT papers that have no solutions because of age and make them do the questions in a non-computer environment.

Comment: Just a couple of ideas you may want to investigate: 1. [Projective planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane); 2. Write an Integer Linear Program ILP in binary variables $x_{i,j}=1$ iff student $i$ has problem $j$, then enforce the maximum size of the intersection applying the logical AND [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp); you may ask ILP specific questions at [or.stackexchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/).